# Not able access a file when using chmod 400

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, terminal

I need to give a user in AWS permission to a key pair using chmod 400 command, but when I do that in the terminal I get an error as attached

```
devmoki@devmoki-HP-250-G2-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo chmod 400 jenkinskeypair.pem
chmod: cannot access 'jenkinskeypair.pem': No such file or directory
```

Have also do this

```
devmoki@devmoki-HP-250-G2-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo !!
sudo chmod 400 jenkins us-west-2 jenkinskeypair.pem
[sudo] password for devmoki: 
chmod: cannot access 'jenkins': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'us-west-2': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'jenkinskeypair.pem': No such file or directory
```

still getting the same error any assist on the same

Comment: SSh keys are usually in ~/.ssh folder. Did you check there?

Comment: Yeah sure sorted got the command from ec2 connect page on AWS, thank you

Comment: Cool. I will make an answer if you dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments. The key was found.

Useful materials with AWS provided info about connection to EC2 are:

- [Connecting to your Linux instance using SSH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)
- [New: Using Amazon EC2 Instance Connect for SSH access to your EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/)